# Ruby on Rails forms: missing template on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

My controller has two methods: index and search.

`def index`: renders the default view, `index.html.erb`, and displays a default map using YM4R/GM.

`def search`: renders the default view using `render index`, but uses form input to display a custom map using YM4R/GM.

The view, `index.html.erb`, contains a partial view, `_form.html.erb`, and the `@map.div` for YM4R/GM.

The map displays fine when rendered through the default, but when submitted to the search method I get the error:
`Template is missing.  Missing template ym4r/gm_plugin/variables/_variable.erb in view path app/views`.

What's weird is that I had this working yesterday until I started jacking around with trying to make my form submit using `form_remote_tag`.  I started getting this error with that type of call so now I've changed everything back (I think), but I'm still getting the error.  I think there's something I don't understand about how Rails renders views.

Comment: I love these errors, when firstly everything works, then I change something and it gets broken, then I undo everything, but the error remains the same :D Love it!

Comment: Okay.  I fixed it by changing `render index` to `render 'index'`.  Could any offer an explanation of the difference?

Comment: Yeah, plain index is looking for a method called index, while the string index will look for the template index.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed out here, there's an important difference between a method and a string.

```
# Call the index method, then render the result, whatever that is. Does not work as
# expected.
render(:action => index)

# Render using the index template
render(:action => 'index')
```

Ruby is really relaxed when it comes to calling methods so there's no requirement to use brackets as is the case with others such as JavaScript or Perl.

Comment: Nice explanation for the sake of posterity.